# How to update rows with ids from one list with values from another list

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a simple MySQL/SQL expression to update records who's IDs are in a list, with values provided by another list?

EXAMPLE:

```
List of customer ids -

  001, 002, 003, 004, ... (etc. list of 1000+ customer ids)

List of order ids -

  00A, 00B, 00C, 00D, ... (etc. list of 1000+ order ids)
```

I want a simple way to do the following without having 1000+ SQL statements like this -

```
update order set orderId = '00A' where customerId = 001;

update order set orderId = '00B' where customerId = 002;

update order set orderId = '00C' where customerId = 003;

etc.
```

NOTE: The lists are in the correct sequence of customerId to orderId, 001 is for order 00A, 002 is for order 00B, etc.

Comment: Is there a simple MySQL/SQL expression to update records who's IDs are in a list, with values provided by another list? No 1000+ separate SQL statements are more simple.. Because the one SQL statement needs to generate the correct orderId foreach customerId.. Also hard to answer without knowing table structures and example data.. So the 27th customerId `027` needs to have a orderId of `0A0` to check it i understand the sequence ?

Answer (score 1):

If the order id's are simply the hexadecimal value of the customer id, then you can do this:

```
UPDATE `order` SET orderId = LPAD(HEX(customerId+9), 3, '0');
```

If you want more control over the mapping, I would create a table with the mapping:

```
CREATE TABLE customerid_orderid (
  customerId char(3),
  orderId char(3),
  PRIMARY KEY (customerId, orderId)
);
```

Load it with the pairings you want.

Then do a multi-table UPDATE:

```
UPDATE `order` AS o
JOIN customerid_orderid AS c USING (customerId)
SET o.orderId = c.orderId;
```

PS: You might find it more convenient to avoid using [SQL reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) (like `order`) as your table name.

Comment: @ABogus Note that this approach only supports up to 4086 customerId's.. customer id 4087 will be broken because the hex is 4 chars width instead of three. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340e01/435 +1 for the find it's nice.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The OP needs to provide more details about how order ID's are formatted from customer ID's.